# Where can I buy a ubuntu phone for the US?

Tags: phone

According to this article 3 are available in the US.  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/09/do-you-plan-to-buy-an-ubuntu-phone  However its not clear to me how to get one.  What are the carrier options? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BQ offers global shipping when ordering from their online shop:

https://store.bq.com/gl/ubuntu-edition-e5/

But you should be aware of the compatibility to only two carriers at the moment, which you can read about here:

http://www.technobuffalo.com/2015/08/09/first-ubuntu-phone-is-now-available-in-the-u-s-but-with-a-catch/

Meizu does not offer global shipping at the moment, as far as I know. At least there is no reference to a US reseller.

Comment: and the meizu does 2g only in the US (unlike the what the article states) , I got one. (only through a friend that then shipped it), and you can always get a nexus 4 on ebay and flash it (as that is the official  device for development)